# How to generate random uniform distribution down a column of values in a dataframe without having to repeat for every value in said column?

Tags: r, random, apply, data-generation, uniform-distribution

I need to create generate random variables based on a uniform distribution using the `runif` command. I have a column of values that the max and min will be based off. I was wondering if there is a way to apply the `runif` down the column without having to repeat the process for each value in the column of values? No others can be used. We're working with `rnorm` and `runif`, etc. so no other stats stuff allowed.

For example:

```
set.seed(1234)
values <- (30, 45, 80, 90, 80)
var_1 <- runif(5, 30*(.5), 30*(1.25))
var_2 <- runif(5, 45*(.5), 45*(1.25))
var_3 <- runif(5, 80*(.5), 80*(1.25))
var_4 <- runif(5, 90*(.5), 90*(1.25))
var_5 <- runif(5, 80*(.5), 80*(1.25))
```

This is basically what I'd have to do but only it's a larger data frame than just five observations. I also have to generate many more random numbers than just 5. I was hoping there was a way to expedite that process so I didn't need to repeat the `var_3 <- runif` part for every row in my datagram. If it helps, I can turn the column of the dataframe into a matrix with a single column and multiple rows. Eventually, I'll be sampling from these randomly generated numbers to perform a Monte Carlo simulation.

I'm assuming some apply function would work, but I'm still not certain how anything from the apply family works. I have looked into some already posted answer but the answers were a bit over my head and I couldn't change them to help me as I had initially thought I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
values <- c(30, 45, 80, 90, 80)

mat <- sapply(values, function(x) runif(5, x*(.5), x*(1.25)))

colnames(mat) <- values

mat

> mat
           30       45       80        90       80
[1,] 15.79778 33.49176 82.79809 106.63342 84.65663
[2,] 27.71421 27.73334 46.04614 108.84509 94.95845
[3,] 21.30580 26.88622 97.01830  63.84305 99.67589
[4,] 19.59442 37.19917 47.30907  53.33430 96.54164
[5,] 18.00913 23.80419 53.17940  98.80833 69.16812
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using inverse probability integral transform:

```
set.seed(1234)
values <- c(30, 45, 80, 90, 80)
n <- length(values)
m <- 10L
t(values * t((1.25 - 0.5) * matrix(runif(m*n), m, n) + 0.5))
```

CDF of OP's distribution is F(x) = 1 / (1.25 - 0.5) * ( x - 0.5 ). 
Hence, F^{-1}(u) = (1.25 - 0.5) * u + 0.5.

We generate standard uniform random variables and transform into the desired distribution using inverse PIT using this F^{-1}(u).

The two `t` operations are i) for easy scaling by `values` and ii) to ensure that the output is in the same format.

Reference:

1. Inverse transform sampling, Wikipedia,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling